# How can PHP bypass string in mathematic operations?

Tags: php, string

```
$str = 'we123'+'123we'+'we'+'123';
```

`echo $str;` Gives output `246`

```
$str = 'we123'-'123we'-'we'-'123';
```

output is `-246`

```
$str = 'we123'*'123we'*'we'*'123';
```

output is `0`

I am not getting any `warning` or `notice`  during this operations.

But In division operation,

```
$str = 'we123'/'123we'/'we'/'123';
```

Gives,

> Warning: Division by zero

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How is it possible? Read about [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) which is one of the absolute fundamentals of PHP

Comment: u r trying to do this  246 /0

Comment: Strings are casted to integers, so alpha characters will be removed.

Comment: And if you really need to throw arbitrary string values into a multiplication or division, test that those values are numeric first..... [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) might help you

Comment: PHP is quite clever, if the first characters of a string are numeric it will use those numerics, up to the first alpha in a calculation. But this `'we123'/'123we'/'we'/'123';` generates `0/123/0/123` and there is your division by zero

Comment: i am trying it in my local with this $str = 'we123'/'123we'/'we'/'123'; but its working properly and give me result : 0

Comment: @jilesh: enable error reporting u will get the warnings... it will give u 0 along with warnings.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: String who start with digit is accepted but who end with digit is not accepted. Am I correct?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything. I bet you get errors shown then

Comment: @MarkBaker: Your link is very useful. I have never experienced type juggling concept before. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ravi Yes. `123xx` will use `123` in a numeric calc situatuation, but `xx123` will be treated as an alpha and the trailing `123` will be ignored. __I hope this is just for interest__, as it is much safer to ensure your data is numeric before attempting any calculation with it

Answer (score 3):

It is how PHP works, look at [PHP string conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Quote from this page:

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Your strings are evaluated in numeric context, thus:

`'we123'` - becomes 0, `'123we'` - becomes 123, `'we'` - becomes 0, `'123'` - becomes 123

Then calculating 0 / 123 / 0 / 123 gives division by zero as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is useful :)